# Distribution and its notation about integral interval

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I'm studying about Dirac delta function.
The Dirac delta distribution is distribution. So it is defined as following:
$$\delta[\varphi]=\varphi(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx$$

The first line is definition of Dirac delta as distribution, second line means also Dirac delta as distribution but it doesn't mean ordinary integral;it is abuse of notation

And i have seen formula as following:
$$\int_{-1}^{4} \delta(x) \, (x^2+1) \, dx$$

The formula above is reasonable? I think 'from -1 to 4' isn't reasonable. Althoug notation in the first picture isn't really mean integral. I think the integral must 'from -infinity to infinity not -1 to 4'

What am I misunderstanding? Or is it related to restriction of distribution?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  (x^2+1)\,\chi_{[-1,4]}(x) \delta(x) \, dx=\int_{-1}^{4}  (x^2+1)\, \delta(x) \, dx$$

Comment: To continue the abuse of notation in some proper way like you want, you're misunderstanding what $\varphi$ is. It is not $(x^2+1)$ but rather $(x^2+1)\chi_{[-1,4]}$ which retrieves the "formula" of the form $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you,is the thing in question what you mean??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Ninad Munshi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/698724/ninad-munshi) [writes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4738004/distribution-and-its-notation-about-integral-interval#comment10046692_4738004), the integral
$$
\int_{-1}^{4} \delta(x) \, (x^2+1) \, dx
$$
can be seen as the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, (x^2+1) \chi_{[-1,4]}(x) \, dx,
$$
where $\chi_{[-1,4]}$ is the indicator function on $[-1,4],$ i.e. it equals $1$ on $[-1,4]$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Now, in general one may not multiply a distribution with a function that is not smooth ($C^\infty$) but when they have disjoint [singular support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Singular_support) such a product can be defined. Evenmore, for $\delta$ it's enough that the function is continuous at $x=0.$ And so is the case for $(x^2+1) \chi_{[-1,4]}(x)$.

The value of the above integral is of course $0^2+1=1$ since $x\in[-1,4].$

Comment: Thank you, but i'm still doubtful about integration -1 to 4, integral symbol in singular integral only means 'notation' not ordinary integral although in ordinary integral it is vaild that the integral from a to b change to integral from c to d when there is indicator function in integrand. But integral symbol at singular distribution is only notation, not ordinary integral. How can applicable property of integral to distribution? Is this property also from regular distribution like derivative of distribution??

Comment: And i'm not sure about  "they have disjoint singular support such a product can be defined." in your answer. You mean dirac delta and indicator function by 'they' and singular support mean ' dirac delta function at zero' and ' indicator function at -1,4'? Thank you @md2perpe

Comment: The integral is abuse of notation. What we actually mean is $\delta\{(x^2+1)\chi_{[-1,4]}\}$ (or something equivalent). We can even consider the derivative $D\delta\{(x^2+1)\chi_{[-1,4]}\}$ since this just becomes $-\delta\{D((x^2+1)\chi_{[-1,4]})\}=0$ since the derivative of the test function is $0$ at $x=0.$

Comment: @김형주. The singular support of $\delta$ is $\{0\}$ while the singular support of $\chi_{[-1,4]}$ is $\{-1,4\}$ (two points). Since $\{0\} \cap \{-1,4\} = \emptyset$ the two distributions (of which one is even a function) have singular support. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338283/168433) you can find how to define the product of two distributions with disjoint singular support.

Comment: Thank you, but what does mean singular support exactly??

Comment: @김형주. Shortly described, it's the set where the distribution doesn't coincide with a $C^\infty$ function. A distribution $T$ can often be given by a function $f$: $$T\{\varphi\}=\int f(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx.$$ If $f \in C^\infty$ then the distribution is called *smooth*. A distribution can be smooth on a subdomain although it's not smooth on the full domain, e.g. $\delta$ is smooth on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ since on that set it coincides with the smooth function $f(x)\equiv 0.$ The singular support is the complement of the largest open set on which the distribution is smooth.

Comment: Thank you for answer i have a question about 'here' (https://math.stackexchang.com/a/2338283/168433). I'm sorry to i ask here, i tried to but my reputation is under 50. So i can't.  Anyway, the in expansion of uv, the second term is (psi_u×u)×((1-psi_v)*v). In here ((1-psi_v)*v) meet the condition for test function(assume it have compact support) but (psi_u×u) isn't smooth in here i have to consider the (psi_u×u) as distribution and ((1-psi_v)*v) as test function?? Or am i all wrong from start??

Comment: @김형주. $\psi_u u$ is a smooth function times a distribution, thus a distribution. $(1-\psi_v)v$ is also a smooth function times a distribution, but since $v$ is smooth on the support of $1-\psi_v$ we can identify the result with a smooth function. Thus, $((1-\psi_v)v) (\psi_u u)$ is a smooth function times a distribution, i.e. a distribution. There is no test function in this expression.