# Does all the well defined product of Hyperfunction satisfy the product rule

Tags: complex-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I read in the first two chapters of Urs Graf's "Introduction to Hyperfunctions and Their Integral Transforms". On the page 114 of the book, The book well defined the product of hyperfunctions in two cases. `2.5.1 Product of Upper or Lower Hyperfunctions` and `2.5.2 Products in the Case of Disjoint Singular Supports`. However, the book does not mention the product rule for "Products in the Case of Disjoint Singular Supports" as follows:

$$D(f\cdot g)=Df\cdot g+f\cdot Dg$$

I think this situation should also be satisfied. But it's not mentioned in the book, and all the previous situations mentioned this point, which makes me a bit skeptical.
Does all the well defined product of Hyperfunction satisfy the product rule?

Comment: In the case of disjoint singular supports the product is everywhere a product of a smooth function and a singular distribution, so the product rule should apply.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338283/168433

Comment: @md2perpe Is it the same for hyperfunctions？

Comment: I don't even know the definition of hyperfunctions.

Comment: @md2perpe Oh,it's a pity.This is the relevant Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfunction

Comment: Ah, I've seen that before. But what is an upper/lower hyperfunction and how is the product defined?

Comment: @md2perpe Here is another link, which provides the PDF of Urs Graf's "Introduction to Hyperfunctions and Their Integral Transforms" in the "References" section at the bottom of this webpage: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hyperfunction

Comment: If I understand it correctly, an upper hyperfunction is more-or-less just the boundary behavior of a function which is holomorphic on the upper complex half-plane (positive imaginary part), and the derivative of it is the ordinary derivative.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, I think it is like this. The book states on page 115 (not the number of pages in the PDF) that it satisfies the product rule, but it is not stated in section 2.5.2